# Checking if the Given numger is an Armstrong number with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, java-stream

I'm having an issue while checking if the supplied number is **Armstrong** or not.

I'm passing the `int` value of `370`, but as a result I'm getting the value of `343`.

Can someone point out what I'm missing?

**Input:** `370`
**Expected:** `370`

```
static int isArmStrong(int num) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num)
            .map(i -> i / 10)
            .map(i -> i % 10)
            .reduce(1, (a, b)-> (b * b * b));       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we need to generate list of Armstrong number between a range in Java 8 Streams.

```
static List<Integer> armStrongBetweenNum(int start,int end){
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list=IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
            .filter(i->isArmStrong(i)).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return list;
}
```

Main function(call)

```
System.out.println("Armstrong num between given end points ->"+armStrongBetweenNum(1, 500));
```

output

```
Armstrong num between given end points ->[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the digits of the given number. But instead you've created a stream of numbers from `1` to the given number inclusive.

And you've hard-coded the *power* of `3` is  (i.e. your solution is intended to deal only with 3-digit numbers).

Also, there's a bug in the `reduce` operation:

```
reduce(1,(a,b)-> (b*b*b))
```

What your method is actually returns is a cube of the last element in the stream, which for the input `370` happens to be a `7`. Because you are ignoring the argument `a` in the accumulator (`a` - represents a sum accumulated so far and `b` - is a next element).

And it'll be better if `isArmstrong` method would return a `boolean` value. Because it's meant to perform a check as you've and by convention methods that start with `is` or `has` are expected to return a `boolean`.

To address this problem correctly, you need to follow the classical algorithm ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number#Java)) iterating over the digits of the given number.

You can do it with streams by the `iterate()` operation. Its **Java 8** flavor which take two arguments (*a **seed** and a **unary operator** that is used to generate the next element*) creates an *infinite stream*. You need to apply the `limit()` operation to trim the *number of elements* in the stream to the *number of digits* in the given number.

Apply `map()` to obtain the *power of every element* and then apply the terminal operation `sum()` to get the result.

```
public static boolean isArmstrong(int num) {
    return num == getArmstrongSum(num);
}

public static int getArmstrongSum(int num) {
    int pow = String.valueOf(num).length();
    return IntStream.iterate(num, i -> i / 10)
            .limit(pow)
            .map(i -> (int) Math.pow(i % 10, pow))
            .sum();
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getArmstrongSum(370));
    System.out.println(isArmstrong(370));
}
```

**Output**

```
370
true
```

Comment: Actually i am using Java 8, in this version method Iterate accepts only 2 variable as iterate(Int seed , IntUninaryOprator f). in compare to your solution iterator accepts three param.

Comment: @ Alexander Ivanchenko i am taking a simple approach, without Math.Pow
() function, trying to iterate using lenth like below.

Comment: @ Alexander Ivanchenko i am taking a simple approach, without Math.Pow
() function, trying to iterate using lenth like below.----
static void armstongViaBasicJava(int num) {
  int r,total=0,temp;
  temp=num;
  while(temp !=0) {   
   r=temp%10;
   total=total+r*r*r;
   temp=temp/10;   
  }
  if(num==total) {
   System.out.println(num +" is a armstrong num");
  }else {
   System.out.println(num + " is not a armstrong num");
  }
 }
Step 1- define a loop /Iteration while num !=0 till iteration continues
Step 2- num % 10
Step 3- total=Total+(r*r*r)
Step 4 temp=temp/10

Comment: @Maveric If usage of `Math.pow` is the part that you can't use for some reason. It could be substituted with a nested stream `map(i -> IntStream.generate(() -> i).limit(pow).sum())` Are you OK with it?

Comment: @Maveric I've explained in the answer why this isn't a good approach `total=total+r*r*r;`. It limits you solution to only **three-digit numbers**, it'll not be able to process correctly input like `27` or `850` (reread the answer carefully and take a look at the wikipedia link, you'll see a traditional solution with loops there). If you have any specific requirements, you **should list of them in the question**.

Comment: Appreciate your effort and apologise to reply late, still my question is open as i told you i am using java 8 and it doesn't support method .takeWhile(i -> i > 0) with iteration, this method is available in from java 9. still not able to resolve this via stream,But thanks for giving me a solution, i ahve also tried this with filter but not sure how to apply terminal operation after filter. for now i need to switch on java 9

Comment: @Maveric Correct `takeWhile` comes from Java 9, missed it. It could be replaced with `limit`. Amended (both code and description), try it out.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the List of Armstrong number with java 8 stream.

```
static boolean isArmStrong(int num) {
    return num==armStrongViaStream(num);
}

//via Stream
static int armStrongViaStream(int num) {
    int size = String.valueOf(num).length();
    return IntStream.iterate(num, i->i/10)
            .limit(size)
            .map(i-> (int)Math.pow(i%10, size))
            .sum();
        }

//List via Stream
static List<Integer> armStrongListUpto(int num){
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list=IntStream.rangeClosed(0, num)
            .filter(i->isArmStrong(i)).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
return list;    
}
```

Main Method

```
System.out.println("List via Java Stream ->"+armStrongListUpto(500));
```

Output will return a list.

```
List via Java Stream ->[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407]
```

Comment: So @Maveric, that is your way to express gratitude? I've explained your mistakes in detail, provided a solution also accompanied by an explanation. And a few days after, you are posting the **same code** as if it's your own answer that you allegedly came up with. You think it's a fair way of dealing with people that are that taking their time to help you?

Comment: Don't take me wrong @Alexander Ivanchenko. i am new to this portal and don't know the rules...my intention is not to hurt you...Yes i am accepting that you have provided me a solution and explained my mistake, i am not here to take any credit..but with the help of your solution i am able to generate the list.. so i have posted it over here to help others.

Comment: Don't avoid my questions, you are **duplicating the code from my solution**. What I'm *"getting wrong"*? There's nothing to do with the list here, it isn't a part of the original question. **Your answer is a duplicate**.